# The View won't show up until async function's callback is finished

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

What I want to do is:

1. I have a web page which is a ASP.NET MVC page;
2. I want to sent a notification email background, after someone post information through my page;
3. The notification email is not critical if it is failed to send out;

I used async call SendAsync(). I traced the code, the controller returned, and async method is also returned, but somehow the View didn't show up in the Browser until the callback completed. So, actually this make async function meaningless at all.

I don't know why, does somebody know what's going on inside the ASP.NET MVC framework?

here is my code sample:

(Controller.cs)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel myModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_myService.ProcessForm(myModel))
            {
                Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                    _notificationService.SendEmail(myModel.Message));
            }

            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
        }

        return View(myModel);
    }
```

(NotificationService.cs)

```
public class NotificationService : INotificationService
{
    //ingore codes for brief

    public NotificationService()
    {
    }

    private bool SendMessage(string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            // Specify the message content.
            message = new MailMessage(fromAddr, toAddr);
            message.Body = msg;
            message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            message.Subject = "Notification";
            message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            // Set the method that is called back when the send operation ends.
            client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

            string userState = message.Body;
            client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            //Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void SendEmail(string msg)
    {
        Task.Run(() => SendMessage(msg));
    }

    private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
        String token = (string)e.UserState;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
        }
        // Clean up.
        if (message != null)
            message.Dispose();
    }
```

Code result:
My "Thank you" page won't show in the browser until SendCompletedCallback() is completed.

I'll popup a "Thank you" page in my heart to everybody! :)

Comment: "I'll popup a "Thank you" page in my heart to everybody!".....huh?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: Suddenly my code works, it is really asynchronized! I don't know why, It's weird I didn't do anything difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494581/how-do-i-properly-execute-an-async-method-in-asp-net-mvc) question and answer.  Considering that HTTP is connection oriented, in general it does not make sense to return a result to the client and continue processing on the server something that will not be returned to the client (at least not via that HTTP session).

Cases where you want to fire off some tangential process like sending an email are certainly exceptional circumstances.  You can use the solution in the original link. Alternatively, you can create an AJAX request that fires off this secondary process.

E.G. jQuery example

```
//Do GET request to gather HTML
//Do POST to fire off email
$('#sendEmail').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Api/SendEmail",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    //...                 
                }
            }).done(function () {
                console.log('email sent');
            });
```

Comment: Thank you first.
I tried the method from the link you gave me. But it doesn't work out for me. It is the same result with my code: View won't show until call back is finished.
I haven't tried the second script right now.
Again, thank you.

Comment: Since my code worked, may be the first option you gave me in the link also works. I think those are similar.